# Unit price equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

having some trouble with a system of simultaneous equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
50x + 40y = 375  \\
75x + 70y = 621
\end{cases} $$
I know
$x=2.82$
and
$y=5.85$
(I looked it up in the answers), but I have literally no idea how to get there...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

dividing the first equation by $5$ we get
$$10x+8y=75$$
$$75x+70y=621$$
from the first equation we get
$$y=\frac{75}{8}-\frac{5}{4}x$$
plugging this in the second equation we obtain
$$75x+\frac{70\cdot 75}{8}-70\cdot \frac{5}{4}x=621$$
thus you will get
$$\frac{-25}{2}x=-\frac{141}{4}$$
from here you will obtain $x=...$

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what this kind of equation is called? I really need to practice this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have following equations: $$50x+40y=375\tag 1$$  $$75x+70y=621\tag 2$$ 
The above equations can be solved by two methods as follows

1. **Substution** Substituting the value of $y=\frac{75-10x}{8}$ from (2) into (1), we get  $$75x+70\left(\frac{75-10x}{8}\right)=621$$ $$300x+2625-350x=2484$$ $$x=\color{blue}{\frac{141}{50}\approx 2.82}$$ $$y=\frac{75-10\frac{141}{50}}{8}=\color{blue}{\frac{117}{20}\approx 5.85}$$
2. **Cramer's rule**  The values of $x$ & $y$ are calculated as follows 
   $$\frac{x}{\left|\begin{array}\\ \color{red}{375}&40\\ \color{red}{621}&70 \end{array}\right|}=\frac{y}{\left|\begin{array}\\ 50&\color{red}{375}\\ 75&\color{red}{621} \end{array}\right|}=\frac{1}{\left|\begin{array}\\ 50&40\\ 75&70 \end{array}\right|}$$ $$\frac{x}{1410}=\frac{y}{2925}=\frac{1}{500}$$
   $$x=\frac{1410}{500}\ \ \vee\ \ y=\frac{2925}{500}$$
   $$\color{blue}{x=\frac{141}{50}=2.82}\ \ \vee\ \ \color{blue}{y=\frac{117}{20}=5.85}$$